# Find Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android

**HomeActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
initialize();
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
buildLocationService();
getLocationDetails(fioLocation);
icHair = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_hair);
icNail = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_nail);
icSpa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_spa);
icTanning = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_tanning);
setOnClickListenersToIcons();
}
private void setOnClickListenersToIcons() {
icHair.setOnClickListener(new IconClickListener(this, zipCode, locality));
icNail.setOnClickListener(new IconClickListener(this, zipCode, locality));
icSpa.setOnClickListener(new IconClickListener(this, zipCode, locality));
icTanning.setOnClickListener(new IconClickListener(this, zipCode,locality));
}
private void getLocationDetails(FioLocation fioLocation) {
zipCode = fioLocation.getZipcode();
locality = fioLocation.getArea();
}
public static class IconClickListener implements OnClickListener {
private Context context;
private String zipCode;
private String locality;
public IconClickListener(Context homeActivity, String zip, String loc) {
context = homeActivity;
this.zipCode = zip;
this.locality = loc;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("businessType", v.getContentDescription());
if (this.zipCode != null) {
intent.putExtra("zipCode", this.zipCode);
}
if (this.locality != null) {
intent.putExtra("locality", this.locality);
}
context.startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ic_Hair = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_hair);
ic_Nail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_nail);
ic_Spa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_spa);
ic_Tanning = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_tanning);
Bundle intentBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String  businessType = intentBundle.getString(BUSINESS_TYPE);
if (businessType != null && businessType.equals(getString(R.string.hair))) {
ic_Hair.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ic_Nail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ic_Spa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ic_Tanning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
if (businessType != null && businessType.equals(getString(R.string.nail))) {
ic_Hair.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ic_Nail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ic_Spa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ic_Tanning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
if (businessType != null && businessType.equals(getString(R.string.spa))) {
ic_Hair.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ic_Nail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ic_Spa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ic_Tanning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
if (businessType != null && businessType.equals(getString(R.string.tanning))) {
ic_Hair.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ic_Nail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ic_Spa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ic_Tanning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
zipCode = intentBundle.getString("zipCode");
locality = intentBundle.getString(LOCALITY);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
addressProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.addressProgress);
locationLable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationLable);
    }
```

In this case I want to avoid a NullPointerException, and I don't know exactly  which object is null.If one image click in the other activity clicked image is display. please help me.

Comment: In the log you have the exact file and line number where NPE arrised

Answer (score 8):

In MainActivity.java,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ic_Hair = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_hair);
ic_Nail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_nail);
```

no call to setContentView() before `findViewById`

Comment: That is an eagle eye catch

Comment: I really don't think questions like that should receive answers here.

Comment: You're right, was a bit harsh. Just pissed off, because of the question.

Comment: @fabian : i agree when its a case of somebody experienced asking the ques, for beginners it is fine, for once, till they know about asking properly

Comment: @fabian in that case just move on, You dont need to attend every question. Android tag is full of question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `setContentView()` inside `MainActivity.java`. For example: `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

For example:

it should look like this inside `onCreate()`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

do the same type of changes inside `HomeActivity.java`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.home);
```

Comment: please take care of grammars while posting any content! Just a suggestion to improve upon your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `setContentView(R.layout.you_xml)` in `MainActivity.Java`

Maybe it can help you